# Python dictionary behaviour

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm newbie in Python and but experienced developer in C. I was writing a script where in C equivalent of switch/case, i had to do dictionary implementation. What I want to do is basically that the dictionary is set to character/function pairs. And the the character is read from the keyboard.

Here is the code

```
...
def func1():
    print "func1"

def func2(Val):
    print "func2 " + Val

def func3(Val):
    print "func3 " + Val

key=getch()
if key in ['s', 't', 'a']:
    print key
    {'a' : func1(),
     's' : func2("Hello"),
     't' : func3("Bye")                                                              
     }[key]
...
```

The result I'm getting is ehen key **t** is pressed

```
func1
func2 Hello
func3 Bye
```

And not the last function call. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you already call the functions when you put them into the dictionary. Try this:

```
if key in ['s', 't', 'a']:
    print key
    {'a' : lambda: func1(),
     's' : lambda: func2("Hello"),
     't' : lambda: func3("Bye")                                                              
     }[key]()
```

This creates `lambda` expressions (another kind of callable function) wrapping the actual function calls, including their respective parameters (if the function has no parameters, you could also just do `'a' : func1`, without the `()`). You then get the lambda corresponding to the key and call it (note the additional `()` after `[key]`).

Alternatively, you could also create the dict before checking the key:

```
functions = {'a' : lambda: func1(),
             's' : lambda: func2("Hello"),
             't' : lambda: func3("Bye") }
if key in functions:
    functions[key]()
```

Comment: Thanks tobias. The logic works. However, i had to put func1() instead of func1 in dictionary to make it work. Don't know if it's due to old python version or not. I have to look into this lambda functions for full understanding though...

Comment: Yes, `func1` was a typo. Corrected it to `func1()`. Although, for func1 you could actually go without the lambda (see update). So, did this solve your problem then?

Comment: @Indy In this case it would be very nice if you could _accept_ this answer to mark the question as being resolved. ;-)

Comment: Did it. sorry, it wasn't that obvious. I was looking for "solved" button or similar till i realised the tick was the thing to do. Nice but a bit silly from my point of view. But then, I'm old fashioned...